# Are there languages/software that implements http status code 418?

Tags: http, http-status-codes, httpserver

I know that status code 418 was defined as a April Fools' joke, and *"is not expected to be implemented by actual HTTP servers"* as is stated on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_code).

But I would be interested if any of you knew of a language/webserver/IDE that supports it.

I was trying on Apache (via php), and obviously it got me an internal error (500). I just like the humor behind it (am not trying to troll here) and would like to know if more than just Emacs implements this.

---

More precisely: It could be *emulated* in php for example by doing something like ...

```
header("HTTP/1.1 418 Whatever text I'd like");
```

... but do any of you know any actual server software, or **language** in particular, that implements it *natively*, where something like the following would not throw a 500, but actually work:

```
http_response_code(418);
```

Comment: Mine does. It returns 418 if you try to access a feature you haven't unlocked yet, and encourages you to [have some tea and relax](http://q.pokefarm.org/418.php).

Comment: Well but it is still a `200 OK` there, isn't it?

Comment: If you call the page directly, then sure. Just like if you go to any site's `404` page directly, you'll get a `200 OK` of the error document. But if you try to access a feature that you haven't unlocked on my site, it will respond with [a "proper" 418 error code](http://i.imgur.com/mHWrQds.png).

Comment: node.js: res.send(418)

Comment: @Niet: Nice :-) But it is not actually the server supporting this correct? Meaning: You do put it in the header of the response, and not just set it to a 418, which the server knows by itself, is that right? I mean, it works too, but yeah ^^ (still nice way, to use this)

Comment: Right, it is a manual setting to 418. This is because servers aren't teapots, and therefore cannot correctly implement 418 natively. Now, if one were to have a teapot that could be controlled by HTTP, then you could reasonably implement 418 as an appropriate response to `GET /coffee HTCPCP/1.0` or something :p

Comment: I still like that thought a lot ^^

Comment: Well the problem is, that it would have to be @OlegS. 's comment that got the answer to this question. Seems like `node.js` does support 418 natively and his `res.send(418)` sends a proper `I am a teapot` message to go with it! (Which was what I was really looking for) Your answers are great examples none the less, but having server *software* (apache, nginx, etc.) support this natively is just awesome / what I wanted. Sry for being ambiguous in my question (not a native speaker). But thx for reminding, I will write an answer with that. If Oleg also answers, I will delete mine and accept his!

Comment: @Levit no worries, I am happy to bump your answer up

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## Websites that have implemented it

- Google - [www.google.com/teapot](http://www.google.com/teapot) - ([Details from @ButtleButkus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018008/is-there-a-server-that-implements-http-status-code-418/27032308#27032308))
- Stackoverflow on CSRF violations - [Meta question about it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185426/stack-overflow-returning-http-error-code-418-im-a-teapot) - ([Details from @ImmortalBlue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018008/is-there-a-server-that-implements-http-status-code-418/29342497#29342497))
- A teapot - [joereddington.com/projects/418..](http://joereddington.com/projects/418-error-code-teapot/) - ([Details from @MegaTom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018008/is-there-a-server-that-implements-http-status-code-418/27068325#27068325))
- Snarked - [www.snarked.org/coffee](http://www.snarked.org/coffee) - ([Details from @MR.X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018008/is-there-a-server-that-implements-http-status-code-418/29201171#29201171))

## Languages that support it natively

#### Node.js

```
res.send(418)
```

Sends following HTTP header:

```
HTTP/1.1 418 I'm a teapot
Date: Wed, 25 Feb 2015 07:08:27 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

The actual node.js code used to get this response was:

```
require('http').createServer(function(q,s) {
    s.writeHead(418);
    s.end();
}).listen(80);
```

#### Golang

```
http.Error(w, http.StatusText(418), 418)
```

#### Python

Within native libraries, starting from Python 3.9 ([Details @Ross](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60711563/1680919))

Answer (score 37):

Google does it.

Try clicking on the teapot, or tilting your mobile device.

[www.google.com/teapot](http://www.google.com/teapot)

Comment: Surely google.com/brewcoffee would be more appropriate for them to use?!

Comment: `curl -H "Accept-Additions: Chocolate" -X BREW coffee://google.com/breville`

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is implemented (by [a teapot](http://www.joereddington.com/418-error-code-teapot)).

This error code is an impotent part of [HTCPCP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2324)(Hyper Text Coffee Pot Control Protocol).

Answer (score 4):

Python 3.9 will support HTTP 418 from its next (fifth) alpha release. I opened a [pull request](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/18291) for this to be supported which was merged last weekend.

Answer (score 2):

Stack overflow implements it:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185426/stack-overflow-returning-http-error-code-418-im-a-teapot

albeit, a little creative, when dealing with [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) violations.

Answer (score 2):

Go lang's `net/http` package codifies HTTP 418 Status as a constant: [`StatusTeapot`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#pkg-constants).

Comment: Awesome! Thanks ... added to the list.

Answer (score 1):

My server, www.snarked.org, does it if the pathname begins "/coffee" or "/pot-" followed by a digit, or methods BREW or WHEN, or a scheme equating to "coffee:" (actually, the regex pattern "^[CK][AO]FF?[EIO]E?$" which covers most western-European languages).  After 60 seconds, it rolls over to Google's top hit for teapots.